# Why does my browser not show the css button in the html script?

Tags: html, css, button, localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="Button1" rel:"stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>
</html>
 /* CSS Document */
 type = text/css>
 .button {
 background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

why is this not working. i have built an easy html script and copied a css script from youtube which should build a button (cant write css :-( ). Ive tried to use different ways to include the css script in the html programming. But if i look at the local host i cant see any button

Comment: CSS are not responsible for creating/building anything in HTML. CSS is used just for stylize, if there's no button with class `button` (which is styled in css `.button{...}`) in HTML, so no button will exist

Comment: thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't add any element with class `.button` into your `HTML`. `CSS` doesn't create element, `HTML` does. `CSS` gives styles.

Look in the snippet.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="Button1" rel: "stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
  
  <div class="button">blala</div>
  
  <span class="button">roar</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: rthank you very much :/)